# Problem of `Integrate` and `DSolve` with inhomogeneous Legendre differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, complex

I have the following inhomogeneous Legendre differential equation $(m=n=2)$:

```
 deq=(6 - 4/(1 - z^2)) h2[z] - 
  2 z Derivative[1][h2][z] + (1 - z^2) Derivative[2][h2][z] == (
  6 (-1 + z + z^2) μ^2)/(M^4 (-1 + z^2)^2) + (
  3 μ^2 Log[(-1 + z)/(1 + z)])/(M^4 (-1 + z))
```

where the variable $z>1$. I can not get Mathematica to give me the simplest/correct solutions. I think it has to do with those logarithms. I know that the homogeneous solution is

```
solH=A*LegendreQ[2,2,3,z]+B*LegendreP[2,2,3,z]
```

I need mathematica's type 3 Legendre functions because for $z>1$ the type 3 functions are on the right branch. With `DSolve` however I can only get the expanded forms of type 1:

```
DSolve[deq[[1]] == 0, h2[z], z]
```

gives back

```
 {h2[z] -> -3 (-1 + z^2) C[1] + C[2] (((1 - z^2) (5 z - 3 z^3))/(-1 + z^2)^2 + 
      3 (1 - z^2) (-(1/2) Log[1 - z] + 1/2 Log[1 + z]))}
```

which is not real for $z>1$. Is there a way to tell `DSolve` to work with $z>1$ or to search for real solutions under that assumption? `$Assumptions={z>1}` alone does not do the trick.

Apart from that I have a bigger problem with the particular solution:
`DSolve[deq, h2[z], z][[1]]` gives a ridiculous partial solution which is incredibly long and complex. I want a real particular solution; I want a solution that is real for all $z>1$. I know from literature that there is one (plugging that one in proves that it is indeed one):

```
{h2p[z] -> -3 μ^2/(16 M^4) (6 z^2 + 3 z - 6 - (4 z^2 + 2 z)/(z^2 - 1)) - 3 μ^2/(32 M^4) (3 z^2 - 8 z - 3 - 8/(z^2 - 1)) Log[(z - 1)/(z + 1)] + 3 μ^2/(16 M^4) (z^2 - 1) Log[(z - 1)/(z + 1)]^2}
```

Again is there a way to tell `DSolve` to produce a real solution for $z>1$? I also tried constructing that particular solution using the *Variation of Parameters* method

```
WLQ223LP223 = 
 Wronskian[{LegendreQ[2, 2, 3, z], LegendreP[2, 2, 3, z]}, z]
-LegendreQ[2, 2, 3, z]*
    Integrate[deq[[2]]*LegendreP[2, 2, 3, z]/WLQ223LP223, z] + 
   LegendreP[2, 2, 3, z]*
    Integrate[deq[[2]]*LegendreQ[2, 2, 3, z]/WLQ223LP223, z] // 
  FunctionExpand // Simplify
```

Mathematica finds an analytical  solutions but they do not reduce to the particular solution I want: the involved integrals become very lengthy and again complex.

Anyone around here who has some experience with such differential equations in Mathematica?

I send the problem to a friend who has Maple and Maple's `dsolve` finds the "correct"/simple partial solution, when one prepends `assume(z > 1)`. It does so using the *Variation of Parameters* method and the solutions of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: What is `dgl` ?

Comment: Ah sorry: it is the differential equation I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer [@corey979's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22013/corey979) approach (+1), but with the following tweaks.

```
solExpr = 
  Assuming[z > 1 && M ∈ Reals && μ ∈ Reals,
   DSolveValue[deq, h2[z], z] /. {Log[-1 + z^2] -> Log[-1 + z] + Log[1 + z], 
        Log[(-1 + z)/(1 + z)] -> Log[-1 + z] - Log[1 + z]} // Re // 
     ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify
   ];

sol = h2 -> Function @@ {z, solExpr}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
deq /. sol // Simplify[#, z > 1 && M ∈ Reals && μ ∈ Reals] &
(*  True  *)

Plot[h2[z] /. sol /. {M -> 1, μ -> 1, C[1] -> -1, C[2] -> 1},
 {z, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The main tweaks are including all assumptions to make all parameters real in both `DSolve` and `Simplify` and the use of `TargetFunctions`.  It's also easier to simplify an algebraic expression; hence `DSolveValue[]`. The rules

```
{Log[-1 + z^2] -> Log[-1 + z] + Log[1 + z], 
 Log[(-1 + z)/(1 + z)] -> Log[-1 + z] - Log[1 + z]}
```

help with simplification; they are not important and may be omitted.

The main reason I prefer this is that the real and imaginary parts are independently solutions of a real ODE, a key point made by corey979.  It just seems a simpler approach, when it simplifies down nicely.  In this case it does, and we get a general solution that spans the solution space.

Comment: Well this does the trick in just one line. `TargetFunctions` works nice here and dealing with those logarithms with the rule seems to be a good idea so Mathematica does not start crazy stuff with them. I will accept this answer, since it is the shortest one but all three given until know helped a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

About the homogeneous part:

Let us first define the (comparison) solution with the Legendre functions:

```
solLeg[z_] := B*FunctionExpand@LegendreQ[2, 2, 3, z] + A*LegendreP[2, 2, 3, z]
```

`LegendreQ` doesn't want to display anything friendly in this case, so I used `FunctionExpand` to get a comprehensible result:

```
FullSimplify@solLeg[z]
```

[image]

Next, let's solve the equation:

```
solEq = DSolve[deq[[1]] == 0, h2[z], z, Assumptions -> z > 1] /. {C[1] -> A, C[2] -> B}
```

[image]

I used `Assumptions -> z > 1` to specify the domain and changed the default constant of integration to `A` and `B` just for clarity of the display. Note that there's an $-i\pi$ term before the `Log`s, but the two functions are quite similar to each other.

Now, the crucial points are: **(1)** in general, as can be seen above, the solution is complex, even though the domain `z>1` is real; this is not a suspicious behaviour by itself, differential equations and their solutions are just like that; **(2)** the real and imaginary parts of the solution are together and separately the solutions of the equation; one just has to extract the real part to get the real solution.

I define a *helping* expression:

```
help = h2[z] /. solEq[[1, 1]]
```

to make some manipulations on:

```
sol = Simplify @ PowerExpand @ ComplexExpand @ Re @ help
```

`ComplexExpand @ Re` extracts the *real* (without the imaginary unit $i$) part of `help`; `PowerExpand` is used to convert $\log(x^2)$ into $2\log x$, and `Simplify` as usual. We get

[image]

Finally,

```
sol + FullSimplify@solLeg[z] // FullSimplify
```

> 0

meaning that what Mathematica returns - `solEq` - as the solution of the differential equation is indeed consistent with the solution in a form of Legendre functions `solLeg`.

---

About the inhomogeneous case:

If one runs

```
FullSimplify@
 PowerExpand@
  ComplexExpand@
   Re@First[
     h2[z] /. 
       FullSimplify@
        DSolve[deq, h2[z], z, Assumptions -> z > 1] /. {C[1] -> A, 
       C[2] -> B}]
```

it returns a four-line long expression with `Log`s and `Arg`, and of course with the constants of integration `A` and `B` (it's uninformative enough to not post it here; it should be noted that it takes about 7 seconds to obtain this expression). The particular real solution from the literature, mentioned by the OP:

[image]

has many terms similar to those from the above computation, but no constants of integration in it so I suspect that some initial conditions were employed to obtain it. Once they are provided I expect that a similar treatment as in the homogeneous case could also show that the solutions are equivalent; or maybe it will turn out that `DSolve` will immediately give the expected solution.

Comment: `PowerExpand@ComplexExpand@Re@` seems to be a good start to work with Mathematica's results. I do not think you have to provide initial conditions to get the (or better a) particular solution; those terms involving $A$ and $B$ should be the Legendre polynomials of the homogeneous solutions. I will try to manipulate the particular solution a bit. Those `Arg`'s are no problem they vanish for $z>1$. Maybe I need to add some $Q^2_2$ and $P^2_2$ but it looks promising. Thank you that tip with `PowerExpand@ComplexExpand@Re@` it seems to be in general a good option to get the real part out.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the limited response to question [126132](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126132/1063), it appears that there is no general method for causing `DSolve` to produce results that are free of explicit complex terms.  However, it often is possible to transform the `DSolve` constants of integration to eliminate complex terms, as in [126072](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126090/1063).  For the solution to the homogeneous ODE in the present question,

```
Flatten@DSolve[deq[[1]] == 0, h2[z], z];
Collect[h2[z] /. % /. C[1] -> C[1 ] + C[2] Pi I/2, C[_], FullSimplify[#, z > 1] &]
(* (3 - 3 z^2) C[1] + ((z (-5 + 3 z^2) - 3 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z]) C[2])/(-1 + z^2) *)
```

is free of complex terms.  Eliminating complex terms from the corresponding solution of the inhomogeneous ODE is more involved but can be accomplished by the same general approach.  Starting as before,

```
s1 = Collect[h2[z] /. Flatten@DSolve[deq, h2[z], z] /. 
    C[1] -> C[1 ] + C[2] Pi I/2, C[_], FullSimplify[#, z > 1] &]
(* (1/(16 M^4 (-1 + z^2))) 3 μ^2 (-6 + z (5 + z (16 - 3 z (1 + 2 z))) + 
   I π (1 + z (-5 + z (-2 + z (3 + z)))) + (2 - 3 I π (-1 + z^2)^2 + 
   2 z (4 + z (-10 + z (-4 + 5 z)))) ArcCoth[z] + 
   4 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z]^2 - 7 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcTanh[z]) + 
   (3 - 3 z^2) C[1] + ((z (-5 + 3 z^2) - 3 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z]) C[2])/(-1 + z^2) *)
```

Because `ArcTanh[z]` is complex for `z > 1`, it first should be eliminated, which can be accomplished using the identity

```
FullSimplify[ArcCoth[z] - Pi I/2 == ArcTanh[z], z > 1]
(* True *)

s2 = FullSimplify[s1 /. ArcTanh[z] -> ArcCoth[z] - Pi I/2]
(* (1/(32 (-1 + z^2)))((1/(M^4)) 3 μ^2 (-2 (6 + z (-5 + z (-16 + 3 z + 6 z^2))) + 
   I π (9 + z (-10 + 3 z (-6 + z (2 + 3 z)))) + 2 ArcCoth[z] (-5 - 3 I π 
   (-1 + z^2)^2 + z (8 + z (-6 + z (-8 + 3 z))) + 4 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z])) - 
   96 (-1 + z^2)^2 C[1] + 32 (z (-5 + 3 z^2) - 3 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z]) C[2]) *)
```

Finally, the explicit complex numbers are eliminated by finding the values of `{C[1], C[2]}` that cancel those complex numbers.

```
t1 = Coefficient[s2, Pi] Pi;
t2 = Coefficient[s2, {C[1], C[2]}].{C[1], C[2]};
{C[1], C[2]} /. Flatten@Solve[
    Thread[CoefficientList[t1 - t2, ArcCoth[z]] == 0], {C[1], C[2]}];
Thread[Rule[{C[1], C[2]}, {C[1], C[2]} - %]]
(* {C[1] -> (9 I π μ^2)/(32 M^4) + C[1], C[2] -> -((3 I π μ^2)/(16 M^4)) + C[2]} *)

s3 = Collect[s2 /. %, C[_], Simplify]
(* (1/(16 M^4 (-1 + z^2))) 3 μ^2 (-6 + 5 z + 16 z^2 - 3 z^3 - 
   6 z^4 + (-5 + 8 z - 6 z^2 - 8 z^3 + 3 z^4) ArcCoth[z] + 4 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z]^2) + 
   (3 - 3 z^2) C[1] + ((z (-5 + 3 z^2) - 3 (-1 + z^2)^2 ArcCoth[z]) C[2])/(-1 + z^2) *)
```

free of complex terms, as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much: That does the the trick without trying to get rid of the imaginary part manually: Eliminating it by adjusting the constants of integration is a much better. `s3` was exactly what I was looking for.