# Transform a DSolveValue solution into a reasonable form

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Here are two equations:

```
    eq1 = D[z[x], {x, 4}] + z[x] == 0;
eq2 = D[z[x], {x, 4}] + q^4*z[x] == 0;
```

They only differ from one another by the scale factor q^4, where q>0. I need to solve them in real numbers. If I solve the first one I get

```
  DSolveValue[eq1, z[x], x]

(* E^(x/Sqrt[2]) C[1] Cos[x/Sqrt[2]] + E^(-(x/Sqrt[2])) C[2] Cos[x/Sqrt[2]] + E^(-(x/Sqrt[2])) C[3] Sin[x/Sqrt[2]] + E^(x/Sqrt[2]) C[4] Sin[x/Sqrt[2]]     *)
```

[image]

which is convenient to look at. However, if I solve the second one, I get:

```
 DSolveValue[eq2, z[x], x]

(*  E^((-1)^(3/4) q x) C[1] + E^(-(-1)^(1/4) q x) C[2] + E^(-(-1)^(3/4) q x) C[3] + E^((-1)^(1/4) q x) C[4]   *)
```

[image]

which is alredy less convenient. Since q is real and positive, it is obvious, that the solution is like the solution of eq1, in which we make a replacement: `x->q*x`:

```
    DSolveValue[eq1, z[x], x] /. x -> q*x

(* E^((q x)/Sqrt[2]) C[1] Cos[(q x)/Sqrt[2]] + E^(-((q x)/Sqrt[2])) C[2] Cos[(q x)/Sqrt[2]] + E^(-((q x)/Sqrt[2])) C[3] Sin[(q x)/Sqrt[2]] + E^((q x)/Sqrt[2]) C[4] Sin[(q x)/Sqrt[2]]  *)
```

[image]

However, I cannot find a regular operation which would transform the solution of eq2 into this form.

Any idea?

Comment: Dirty trick, ***not recommended***: `DSolveValue[D[z[x], {x, 4}] + EulerGamma^4*z[x] == 0, z, x] /. EulerGamma -> q`. (Any positive symbolic constant could have worked just as well.)

Comment: @ J. M. I admire this trick, the more that one can use, say, `Pi` instead of the `EulerGamma` . However, I am preparing this for students, and poor students will go crazy with such tricks. They need something more regular.

Comment: Yes, that's why I emphasized "not recommended"... I tried `Assumptions`, but it does nothing useful in this case.

Comment: Similar to questions [126132](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126132/1063) and [126768](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126768/1063).

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Thank you. As much as I understood from your answer, there is no satisfactory answer, as yet, right?

Answer (score 4):

```
eq2 = D[z[x], {x, 4}] + q^4*z[x] == 0;
sol = DSolveValue[eq2, z[x], x]
```

[image]

```
sol2 = ComplexExpand@sol
```

[image]

```
rule = First@
  Solve[{C[1] + C[2] == a, C[3] + C[4] == b, I (C[1] - C[2]) == c, 
    I (-C[3] + C[4]) == d}, {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}]
```

[image]

```
sol2 /. rule // Expand
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Similar to corey979's answer

```
eq1 = D[z[x], {x, 4}] + z[x] == 0;
eq2 = D[z[x], {x, 4}] + q^4*z[x] == 0;

sol1 = DSolveValue[eq1, z[x], x]
```

[image]

The terms without the [`GeneratedParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratedParameters.html) are

```
terms1 = List @@ sol1 /. C[_] :> 1
```

[image]

Using distinct `GeneratedParameters` for `sol2`

```
sol2 = DSolveValue[eq2, z[x], x,
  GeneratedParameters -> d]
```

[image]

Finding the relations between the two sets of `GeneratedParameters`

```
rules =
 Solve[
    Thread[
     (Coefficient[sol1 , #] & /@ terms1) ==
      (Coefficient[
          sol2 /. q -> 1 //
           ComplexExpand[#, Array[d, 4]] &,
          #] & /@ terms1)], Array[d, 4]][[1]] //
  Simplify[#, Element[Array[C, 4], Reals]] &
```

[image]

Substituting the `GeneratedParameters`

```
sol2 = sol2 /. rules // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

Verifying

```
sol1 == (sol2 /. q -> 1)

(*  True  *)
```